# PHP RSA Encryption Logic

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I need to send a password that's RSA encrypted with a public key (along with some other data).  Here are the exact instructions from the documentation for the password:

- Encode password in Base64 and ensure UTF-8 encoding
- Encrypt password with RSA with provided public key, no block mode, and PKCS1Padding
- Encode resulting encryption in Base64 with ensured UTF-8 encoding

Here's the code I'm using that to me seems correct:

```
function encryptPassword($pass) {

    $pass = base64_encode($pass);

    $fp = fopen("./cert.crt", "r");
    $publicKey = fread($fp, 8192);
    fclose($fp);
    openssl_get_publickey($publicKey);

    openssl_public_encrypt($pass, $cryptedText, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);

    return base64_encode(utf8_encode($cryptedText));
}
```

I'm getting an error on the other side saying the password can't be decoded.  Support from them is basically non-existent other than the error message, and them saying everything is correct on their side.  My question is, am I sending what they're asking for according to the documentation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No, you've taken *Base64 with ensured UTF-8 encoding* too literally. `utf8_encode` transforms one textual encoding into another, but `$cryptedText` is not textual. It is a binary string, so you lose some characters during encoding. Simply remove it, because Base64 gives you already a textual representation of the binary data:

```
return base64_encode($cryptedText);
```

Additionally, you probably wanted to pass the public key resource into the encryption function:

```
$key_resource = openssl_get_publickey($publicKey); 
openssl_public_encrypt($pass, $cryptedText, $key_resource, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I threw that utf8_encode in there as a desperation attempt when it wouldn't work.  I've taken that out, and am also now passing the public key resource in there, but I'm still getting the same error from the server.

Comment: You may try `$pass = base64_encode(utf8_encode($pass));`, but other than that, I think this matches the description.